# Proper punctuation

Tags: punctuation

> The fact that the organisation had improved its security, prior to a whistle blower's complaint in 2015 may have worked in it's favour now.

In the above statement, I intend to mean that the organisation improved its security in 2015 after a whistle blower had complained. Should I use a comma(,) after 'prior'  in this statement to convey the right meaning?

Comment: No.  Put a comma after "2015", so that "prior to a whistle blower's complaint in 2015" can be interpreted as a parenthetical explanation.

Comment: Actually in the article, in the preceeding statement(preceeding to the quoted statement) it was discussed about the current situation of the organisation. So can a comma after prior mean 'improved its security previously, to a whistle blower's complaint in 2015' ?Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, "prior" would mean that it had improved its security **before** the whistle blower complained. You could say something like

> The fact that the organisation had priorly improved its security, after a whistle blower's complaint in 2015, may have worked in its favour now.

Or just cut the priorly altogether;

> The fact that the organisation had improved its security after a whistle blower's complaint in 2015 may have worked in its favour now.

Note also that "its" should not take an apostrophe in this case.

Comment: I found this statement in a reputed newspaper known for its high standard of English(atleast that's what my friends told me about the newspaper). Please tell me whether a comma after 'prior' would work out because I believe its a printing mistake.

Comment: No, it wouldn't work. Looks to me as though someone has written *prior to* when they mean *following*. On top of that there's a missing comma and a misplaced apostrophe. Could just be carelessness though.